# Destroy DialogActivity by clicking besides it

Tags: android, dialog, destroy

I have an activity in my project, which is shown as a **DialogActivity** by this entry in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">    </activity>
```

The Activity doesn't overlay the whole screen, so my question is:

**Is it possible to destroy this DialogActivity by clicking besides it?** So as it is possible at a normal Dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme.Dialog sets some padding so it does not overlay the whole screen . if you are interested in destroy the dialog on click at this boundary area , set a touch listener to parent layout , compare X,y with appropriate number so ensure thats its desired region .

Comment: So, first by adding maybe "linearLayout.setOnClickListener(......)" and then "if(position==legalPosition) {...}" it should be possible? I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

For future:
I came up with the same question, but the answer didn't help me.

I endend up, setting a onTouchEvent function. This function raises also besides the dialogview.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("onTouchEvent",event.getX() + " " + event.getY());
    // check if X and Y aren't in dialog area, then finish() or something
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```